# getting multiple rows from db that are associated to previous selected rows. laravel 4.2 php

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

so here is my problem,

for a school project i have to make a quiz website in which a normal user should be able to play a quiz, so i have to show all the questions associated to the quiz and all the answers associated to the question, but when i try to do so it only shows the answers that are associated to the final question. here is my code:

```
    // select the clicked quiz.
    $quiz = Quiz::find($id);

    // get all the question and answer records from db that are associated to the selected quiz.
    $questions = DB::table('questions')->where('quiz_id', $id)->get();

    foreach($questions as $question)
    {
        $answers = DB::table('answers')->where('question_id', $question->id)->get();
    }

    return View::make("quizzes.makeQuiz", [
        "quiz" => Quiz::find($id)
    ])->with('quiz', $quiz)->with('questions', $questions)->with('answers', $answers);
```

and here is the html (using blade):

```
    <h3>{{ $quiz->name }}</h3><br/>

    @foreach($questions as $question)

        <h4>{{ $question->question }}</h4>

        @foreach($answers as $answer)


                <p>{{ $answer->answer }}</p>



        @endforeach            

    @endforeach
```

when i try to do this without a foreach i get an error that says 'Trying to get property of non-object'. i know why i get that error because obviously $questions isn't an object.

help is very much appreciated! thanks for reading!

edit*

alright so i have now changed my code to look like this:

```
    $questions = Question::where('quiz_id', $id)->get();

    foreach($questions as $question)
    {
        $answers = Answer::where('question_id', $question->id)->get();
    }

    $data = [
        'quiz'      => Quiz::find($id),
        'questions' => $questions,
        'answers'   => $answers
    ];

    return View::make("quizzes.makeQuiz", $data);
```

the html is basically the same, it returns the quiz and all the questions associated. but unfortunately it only returns the answers associated to the final questions while each questions has 3 answers. i think the problem lies in $answers but i don't know exactly what i am doing wrong here :( please help! thanks!

*edit

I asked this question a second time and it solved my problem, here is the link:
[retrieving multiple records associated to multiple records laravel 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556018/retrieving-multiple-records-associated-to-multiple-records-laravel-4-2)

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your return statement as such:

```
$data = [
    'quiz'      => Quiz::find($id),
    'questions' => $questions,
    'answers'   => $answers
];

return View::make("quizzes.makeQuiz", $data);
```

You are currently returning an array AND trying to return chained variables. Most likely your `$questions` variable never reaches the view because you are passing an array first.

Plus the fact you were trying to collect the `Quiz` model twice for some reason is just wrong.

Also - why are you mixing `Eloquent` and `Fluent` statements to get your models? Stick to one or the other unless the situation warrants it.

Comment: thanks for the answer i'm gonna try this out in a little while, looks fine though! oh and the eloquent and fluent thing, i don't really know why i did it but it seemed to work fine at first until i ran into this problem :/ i'll try to stick to one from now on though.

Comment: If this worked for you don't forget to mark the answer as solved!

Comment: unfortunately it didn't :p but i have it working now though, thanks for your help kind sir!

Comment: consider posting your solution in case it helps someone else.